# Javascript - function declaration flavours

Tags: javascript, function

There are a couple of ways to declare a function in Javascript. There are 2 ways which I could not understand as to why they are used for. Please see below for the 2 declarations.

```
var G = new function(){}; // special case: object constructor
```

AND

```
var C = (function(){});     // function expression with grouping operators.
```

Answers in fiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: The parenthesis in the 2nd example do nothing.  That's the same as `var C = function(){};`.

Comment: The 1st creates a constructor then immediately calls `new` on it.  So, `G` is an object, not a function.

Comment: ... i.e. either of the examples are function declarations. The first-one will give you an error when you try to call `G` (since it creates an object), the second-one is just a regular function expression with extra brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The first one initializes a new instance of the Object class. The second one doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean [IIFE - Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)?

```
var value = 5;
var C = (function(arg){return arg+1})(value);

value = 10;
console.log(C); // prints 6
```

*a lame example, really...*

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping to clarify what you've written in your question. In JavaScript, there are essentially 2 'styles' of declaring functions: 1) using function declarations or 2) using function expressions. Here are examples:

```
function something () {
  console.log( 'This is a function declaration' );
}

var orAnother = function () {
  console.log( 'This is a function expression' );
};

something(); // 'This is a function declaration' will show up on console
orAnother(); // 'This is a function expression' will show up on console
```

Both are valid ways to create a new function in JavaScript. Both are almost identical except in the way the JavaScript engine compiles these objects prior to execution of code. Function declarations are **hoisted**, a term which means that during the compilation phase, the JavaScript engine will assign the function object value to the function's identifier (i.e. 'something'). Function expressions, on the other hand, are only processed during the execution phase. The variable identifier associated with the function expression will be **hoisted** during compilation phase, but the function object itself won't be evaluated and assigned to the identifier until the execution phase.

Between these two styles of declaring functions, function expressions are the most common form in my opinion.

Another misconception you may hold (I'm assuming based on your example with function G) is that there is a special type of function called a `constructor`. I want to point out that this is **NOT TRUE**. In JavaScript, there is no such thing as a special constructor function. JavaScript only has functions - however, (unfortunately in my opinion) it has tried to mimic other classical languages by allowing you to use the `new` keyword before a function invokation. Here's an example:

```
var cat = function (color) {
  this.color = color;
};

var garfield = new cat('orange'); // garfield is now a new object with a color property of 'orange'
```

However, you can just as easily call the function without a `new` keyword:

```
var oops = cat('orange'); 
/* Depending on which environment you invoke this in, it'll give you different results.
 * In browsers not under strict mode, you'll actually be adding the `color` property to
 * the `window` object.
*/
```